# one click triggers 2 posts

Tags: javascript, http, post

What i am trying to do here is one click that sends out two posts. Here is my html

```
<form id="input" method="post" action="http:\\example.com\try">
      <input type="text" name="info1" id="text1"/>
      <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="input2" method="post" action="http:\\example.com\try">
      <input type="text" name="info2" id="text2"/>
</form>
```

And the script

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#text2").submit();
});
```

what I thought was after I click on the submit button for the first form, the submittion for the second form should also be triggered, I should received 2 posts on my server side ,***example.com/try***. But turns out the server only receives the second post, which is info2 and also according to the chrome console, only the second post was triggered.  Any idea why? is this feasible if not at all? By the way, the server and the APP are in different domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#text2").submit();
```

is triggering a page postback before the original submit event can complete, and post your first form.  Also, instead of calling `submit()` on the submit button, I think it's more standard to call it on the actual form, which for you would be: `$("#input2").submit();`

If you want to post two forms like that, you'll have to fire off ajax requests for both, and handle their callbacks.

Comment: Or ajax the first post and call submit() for the second form in the completion callback

Comment: Yea, but to the best of my knowledge, I would face the cross domain problem when I do AJAX post. Not to mention that, the server and the post thing are in two different domains. thank you

Comment: @ClintHui - if the forms posting to another domain you can look at setting up CORS to enable cross domain ajax, or you might have to re-think this page from scratch and ditch the multiple forms, or just re-think the requirement to have them post one after the other.  I wish I had a better answer for you :(

Comment: @Adam Rackis - Thanx, I will look into the CORS thing. By the way, does it support AJAX post? that's the main thing I concern about